# Change color of custom drawn UIView using block animations

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewanimation

I have a UIView which draws itself via drawRect. I use core graphics and draw a bezier curve. I would like to have an animation which changes the color of the bezier curve drawn on some occasions. However just having the color as a property and changing it in an animation block doesn't work. I also need to ensure that it is redrawn correctly. What is the way to do this? I'm quite new to IOS

Comment: Have done some more googling an found the CA360 project on github (https://github.com/neror/CA360) as well as the following presentation: http://www.slideshare.net/alexisgo1/animation-talk-trim  Seems like I have to use Core Animation. However I would like to know if (and how) it is possible to create a custom property which can be animated using blocks in the same simple way as animatable properties.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do what you are trying to do. The system has special code that knows how to animate changes in it's animatable properties, but it does not support animating changes to any other properties.

To animate a color change, you're going to need to use a CAShapeLayer to do your drawing. the strokeColor and fillColor properties of shape layers are animatable.

Comment: You _can_ make your own animatable properties, but in this case it sounds like a CAShapeLayer is a good solution, so +1 on balance.